# Creating a fade in effect for text (example included)

Tags: javascript, jquery

sorry about the short post but I need some help creating the effect that is show on this website:

http://joelfilipe.com/

Basically I know that you can do it in jQuery doing a "fadeIn" but I am not sure how to approach the 3d effect on the website where it looks like it is landing on the page, I tried to dig into the code and view but was pretty confused. Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use javascript for this, it can be done in CSS alone as shown here.

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300);

body {padding: 0; margin: 0; background-color: #333;}

.container {position: fixed; top: 25%; left: 25%;}

/* make keyframes that tell the start state and the end state of our object */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }

.fade-in {
  opacity:0;  /* make things invisible upon start */
  -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;  /* call our keyframe named fadeIn, use animattion ease-in and repeat it only 1 time */
  -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
  animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;

  -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;  /* this makes sure that after animation is done we remain at the last keyframe value (opacity: 1)*/
  -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;

  -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
  -moz-animation-duration:1s;
  animation-duration:1s;
}

.fade-in.one {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.7s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0.7s;
  animation-delay: 0.7s;
}

.fade-in.two {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.2s;
  -moz-animation-delay:1.2s;
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
}

.fade-in.three {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 1.6s;
  animation-delay: 1.6s;
}

/*---make a basic box ---*/
.box{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: #999;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box fade-in one">
    look at me fade in
  </div>

  <div class="box fade-in two">
    Oh hi! i can fade too!
  </div>

  <div class="box fade-in three">
    Oh hi! i can fade three!
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you could use javascript to activate a CSS animation. You can see an example of something similar here http://www.virginholidays.co.uk/wonderlist

Comment: This is close, but I think that the OP is looking for the "drop" effect as well.  It happens quickly on the example page.  Maybe using a text shadowing to suggest dropping.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wow effects](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/docs.html) this is a full library to create css animation

you can use data-wow-duration data-wow-delay download the css and js files and you will be on your way in no time.

Comment: Here is a link to code pen showing you an example of the WOW animations http://codepen.io/dnajar/pen/XKJqYp